# app crashes after adding SVProgressHUD framework in xcode 12

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-frameworks, carthage, xcode12

I have created a framework of SVProgressHUD using https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/3019#issuecomment-665136323 and added in Xcode project.

Image of general tab of xcodeproj:

[image: Image of general tab of xcodeproj]

Image of build phases tab of xcodeproj:

[image: Image of build phases tab of xcodeproj]

the build was successful but the app crashed and it's not showing any error log either.

it's showing `AppDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x283840470"`

I have already tried various solutions from StackOverflow nothing working. I am using the latest version Xcode: 12.0.1 (12A7300) and running the app on an iPad with the latest os 14.0.1.

How can I fix it? Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: AppDelegate don't have a `window` property. I'd tend to say it's more an issue about SVProgressHUD & iOS 13 with `SceneDelegate` vs `AppDelegate`: https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD/issues/990

Comment: thanks for your comment @Larme . It was the problem with SVProgressHUD. after adding window property crash stopped.